# NTP pool provide only IPv4 records?

Tags: dns, ipv6, ntp

Is it normal that the NTP pool DNS servers provide no `AAAA` records and only `A` records?

I would like to know the IPv6 address of some NTP servers of the pool.

**NTP Test Results - pool.ntp.org**

```
Execution date: Tue, 23 May 2017 23:10:46 GMT
NTP server: pool.ntp.org
test type: Query both.
```

**IPv4 test results**

```
Result:OK
Server:213.251.53.187
Stratum:2
Offset:0.000410
Delay:0.03044
```

**IPv6 test results**

```
Result:Fail
Server:Invalid hostname / IP address
Stratum:0
Offset:0.000000
Delay:0.00000
```

[NTP Test Results - pool.ntp.org @ Tue, 23 May 2017 23:10:46 GMT](https://ncomputers.org/ntptest/20170523-231046-2d2b)

Comment: One test of many provided ``AAAA`` record [NTP Test Results - 2.de.pool.ntp.org @ Wed, 24 May 2017 03:19:50 GMT](https://ncomputers.org/ntptest/20170524-031950-c5e5)

Comment: https://status.ntppool.org has IPv6 servers listed

Comment: everything is operational, however there still a lack of ``AAAA`` records :( [NTP Test Results - pool.ntp.org @ Wed, 24 May 2017 03:42:33 GMT](https://ncomputers.org/ntptest/20170524-034233-329b)

Answer (score 5):

This came up some time ago on the [ntp mailing list](https://lists.ntp.org/pipermail/pool/2015-March/007280.html) and indeed [some](https://news.ntppool.org/2009/11/wwwpoolntporg-is-ipv6-enabled/) servers are now [reachable](https://status.ntppool.org/) via IPv6, but not `pool.ntp.org`, as you noticed yourself:

```
$ host -t aaaa pool.ntp.org
pool.ntp.org has no AAAA record

$ for i in {0..3}; do host -t aaaa $i.pool.ntp.org; echo; done
0.pool.ntp.org has no AAAA record

1.pool.ntp.org has no AAAA record

2.pool.ntp.org has IPv6 address 2001:470:b:862::10
2.pool.ntp.org has IPv6 address 2600:3c00::e:d0bb
2.pool.ntp.org has IPv6 address 2600:3c03::f03c:91ff:fe67:49e9
2.pool.ntp.org has IPv6 address 2001:470:0:2c8::2

3.pool.ntp.org has no AAAA record
```

I'd suggest to inquire again on the [mailing list](https://lists.ntp.org/listinfo/pool) about the IPv6 rollout plans.

Answer (score 1):

Since IPv6 day (in 2011) IPv6 has been on all the 2. NTP pool domains.
So 2.pool.ntp.org and all the 2.[area].pool.ntp.org domains.
e.g. 2.uk.pool.ntp.org which is what I've been using. https://news.ntppool.org/2011/06/experimentally-enabling-ipv6/
https://news.ntppool.org/2011/06/continuing-ipv6-deployment/